# Export big psql table to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, export, psql

how i can export big table to json, but output file is over 1Gb

```
copy (SELECT json_agg(export_data)::text FROM "table_name" export_data) TO '{{ path_name }}/{{ table_name }}.json' with csv quote E'\t' encoding 'UTF8'
```

I receive: out of memory, Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741822 bytes by 1 more bytes.

| Table column: |
| --- |
| First | uuid |
| Second | timestamp |
| Three | uuid |
| Four | timestamp |
| Five | uuid |
| Six | int4 |
| Seven | text |
| Eight | uuid |
| Nine | int4 |
| Ten | uuid |
| Eleven | uuid |
| Twelve | varchar(50) |

Maybe there is a way to split the output by lines?

Comment: you can export your table piece by piece by filtering on some column values

Comment: You can show how do this?

Comment: Highly depends on your table defintion and content. Can you share the table definition first by updating your question ? Is there any column of type date or timestamp ? Any column with a limited set of repeated values  that can be used to partition the table ?

Comment: i update the question

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting the table into several parts and exporting each part separately :**

Let's assume that the size is proportional to the number of rows and decide that one n-th of the total number of rows is a reasonnable size. You can then execute a procedure like the following one and will get n resulting files :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE table_export (table_name text, path_name text, n integer) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  total_count bigint ;
  i integer ;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT
  ( 'SELECT count(*)
       INTO total_count 
       FROM %I'
  , table_name 
  ) ;

  FOR i IN 0 .. (n-1) LOOP
    EXECUTE FORMAT
    (E'COPY ( SELECT json_agg(export_data)::text 
                FROM %1I export_data
               LIMIT %4s
               OFFSET (%3s * %4s)
            ) 
         TO \'%2s/%1s_%3s.json\' with csv quote E\'\\t\' encoding \'UTF8\''
    , table_name
    , path_name 
    , i
    , ceil(total_count/n)
    ) ;
  END LOOP ;
END ;
$$ ;
```